# mvn eclipse:eclipse could not resolve dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I had downloaded the zip from https://github.com/mguessan/java-saml. I am trying to import the maven project to eclipse java project using "mvn eclipse:eclipse". However I encountered the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project java-saml: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.onelogin:java-saml:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.onelogin:java-saml-core:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project java-saml: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.onelogin:java-saml:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.onelogin:java-saml-core:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Full stacktrace: https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cslucas/SF/mvn/debug.txt

I couldn't figure out what is wrong. I also tried mvn clean install and its not working for me.

Comment: Looking at your error stack trace, you seem to be missing **java-saml-core:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT** jar file in **com.onelogin** package in your project.

Comment: `eclipse:eclipse` is obsolete. Use the m2eclipse plugin and File->Import->Existing Maven projects.

Comment: I suggest to validate if that artifact really exists as published on any public maven repository. If not, then replace it using a newer one or maybe version 2.2.1 finallly was fully released as is not a snapshot anymore...

Comment: @Abhinav how do I verify?

Comment: @chrylis how do I use m2eclipse after I import existing maven project

Comment: @JonnathanQ how do I validate?

Comment: @bittersour Probably you may check in the lib folder of the project whether the respective jar is present there or not.

Comment: @bittersour Just Google it, search for "maven java-saml" the first result probably will be the maven repository web page, it'll show you a list of available versions for that artifact

Comment: check your settings.xml in maven config you might be pointing to a url where there is no dependency and hence it is not able to download it. or just check in your eclipse as to which location settings.xml are you pointing to?